# android volley RequestQueue . code in php

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I am setting up a sign in page for Android.

Android request code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://www.MY-URL.ir/signup.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        System.out.println("--------------> res : " + response + " <------------------- res");
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "res", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "-----------------> err", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name","David Lee");
        return params;
    }
};
queue.add(sr);
```

PHP auntification code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $response = array(); 
    $response['name'] = $name; 

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $no_data=array();
    $no_data['none']= 'no data received';
    echo json_encode($no_data);
}
?>
```

I am sending David Lee as a name and I want to insert it in a database (MySQL)

```
params.put("name","David Lee");
```

But I can't recognize the result of the request in my Php MySql table.
Is my code right?

Authentication request returns the following response:

```
System.out: --------------> res : <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("1ab6d8dc093d812e09e8e3d3ffcb99d5");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://www.papyrusmarket.ir/signup.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html> <------------------- res
```

How should back-end send the response to android? And how can I get it?